# how can I get a staff member's supervisor using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

hello I need to get an employee's supervisor name 
so

```
desc staff;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| StaffNo      | varchar(6)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Lastname     | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Firstname    | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Hire_date    | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Location     | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SupervisorNo | varchar(6)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Salary       | decimal(8,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Commission   | decimal(4,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

so the employee last name is McLester

I tried using this method but it doesn't work

```
select lastname
    -> from staff
    -> where staff.staffno = staff.supervisorno AND lastname = 'McLester';
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO. Step 1. See about JOINs. If you're still struggling, then Step 2. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can self-join the table:

```
select t1.Lastname
from mytable t
inner join mytable t1 on t1.staffNo = t.SupervisorNo
where t.Lastname = 'McLester'
```